# Changing the group name and version of k8s API

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I am using custom metrics API for autoscaling. I have used an external REST API service to handle the get request from HPA. I wanted to change the group and version name in the standard structure of URL mentioned in [k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/).

structure:

```
GET /apis/GROUP/VERSION/namespaces/NAMESPACE/RESOURCETYPE/NAME
```

my url:

```
/apis/***custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1***/namespaces/default/services/my-API/metric-value
```

I wanted to change the group name `custom.metrics.k8s.io` to some `mycustom.metrics.k8s.io`.
As this group name and version is there in `custom-metrics-api-service.yaml` (in the end I have attached the yaml file). I tried to change the group name but then HPA was not able to retrieve the metrics value. Looks like HPA was still looking for that custom.metrics group.

So is it possible to change that group and version name in standard url? If yes then what all the files that I need to change?

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  group: custom.metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 1000
  versionPriority: 5
  service:
    name: my-API
    namespace: default
  version: v1beta1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom.metrics.k8s.io` is the name of aggregated series API and can not be changed.